# Curiosity about large and small sets

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be a given set of positive integers. In the combinatorial sense, $A$ is then small if
$$\sum_{a\in A}\frac{1}{a}< \infty,$$
and $A$ is large otherwise.

From what I've read, it is hard to give give general criteria to determine whether a given set $A$ is small or large, and I've seen some interesting examples of different small sets.

One of the more interesting examples of a small set I've seen is the following:

> Let $A_k={\lbrace a\in \mathbb{N}: \text{the integer }k \text{ does not appear in }a \rbrace}$, for $k=0,1,...,9$. Then $A_k$ is a small set.

This recently got me thinking about the following quotient:

> For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $Q_n:2^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by 
>   $$Q_n(A)=\frac{|{\lbrace a\in A: a\leq 10^n\rbrace}|}{10^n}$$

For instance,

$$Q_1(A_9)=0.9, \quad Q_2(A_9)=0.81, \quad Q_3(A_9)=0.729, \quad Q_4(A_9)=0.6561,$$ and so on.

Now for my main question:

> Do we have that $Q_n(A_k)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for $k=0,1,...,9$? And more generally, if $A$ is a small set, do we have that $Q_n(A)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

I suspect that the answer to this question is yes, but I'm not sure how one should go about proving it formally (I imagine one would use some sort of contradiction proof and lower bounds on partial sums, but I'm not sure).

My main question also motivates the follow-up question:

> If $Q_n(A)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, can we say for sure that $A$ is a small set? If not, what counterexamples are there?

I suspect that the answer to this question is no, but I have no idea how to construct a counterexample.

Comment: If $P$ is the set of primes, then $Q_n(P)\to0$, but $P$ is not small.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yeah, guess that settles the follow-up question then.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first question, let $k \in \{0, ... , 9\}$. Now, let's count
$\{a \in A_k : a \leq 10^n \}$ . Numbers in this set have a decimal representation of
$$
10^{n-1}b_{n-1} + \ ...\  + b_0
$$

with $b_i \in \{0, ... , 9\} - \{k\}$. Therefore, we have a total of $9^{n}$ possible numbers. This shows that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} Q_n(A_k) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{9^{n}}{10^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} (0.9)^{n} = 0
$$

Comment: Oh yeah, this is a good way to do it. But I suspect it's supposed to be $9^n$ instead of $9^{n-1}$, since there are $n$ numbers between 0 and $n-1$. But that is more of a side remark than anything.

Comment: The $n-1$ is because if we have a number that has a nonzero digit at the $j$-th place with $j \geq n$, it is larger than $10^n$. The 9 comes up when counting the amount of possible numbers for each digit: we have $10$ numbers available, $9$ when we remove $k$.

Comment: This seems strange to me, since the formula doesn't work then. Just explicitly calculating we get that $10^n \cdot Q_n(A_k)=9^n$ for small values of $n$. We have that $B=\lbrace{b_0,b_1,...,b_{n-1}\rbrace}$ contains $n$ elements, since we begin at 0 and not at 1.

Comment: Oh well, I messed up my indexes. You're totally right. I'll edit it.

Comment: No problem, it doesn't really matter much in either case.

Comment: There, fixed it :)